# Hibernate SessionFactory not getting created due to inability to locate the my.hbm.xml files by mappingResource, see the screenshots

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory, hbmxml, mapping-resources

`@Configuration` class having one of the `@bean` declaration for hibernate `SessionFactory`. its `mappingResource("hbm file path")` method is not locating `my.hbm.xml` and hence getting "`cannot be opened because it does not exists.`" I applied many strategies but no luck any help will be appreciated. For clear exposure, added screenshots as well.

[image: project folder structure]

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory() {
LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
sessionFactory.setDataSource (dataSource());
sessionFactory.setLobHandler(lobHandler());
List<String> mappingResources = new ArrayList<>();
mappingResources.add("hibernate/Customer RequestDTO.hbm.xml");
mappingResources.add("hibernate/AccessRequestDTO.hbm.xml");
mappingResources.add("hibernate/AccessRequestItemDTO.hbm.xml");
sessionFactory.setMappingResources (mapping Resources.toArray(new String[mappingResources.size()]));
sessionFactory.setHibernate Properties (hibernateProperties());
try {
sessionFactory.after PropertiesSet();
} catch (java.lang. Exception e) {
LOG.error("Error creating Session Facotry", e);
}
return (SessionFactory) sessionFactory.getObject();
}
```

Issue : `java.io.FileNotFoundException : Class Path Resource [CutomerRequestDTO.hbm.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exists.`

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Your resources are in `hibernate/` you should prefix them with that so `hibernate/CustomerRequestDTO.hbm.xml`.

Comment: edited please check now. prefix is having hibernate/ for each x.hbm.xml

Comment: Looking at your screenshot I'm not sure where they are but `src/main/resources` isn't a source directory. Looks like you modified something in the pom.xml so use something different.

Comment: Denium, can you explain this bit clearly

Comment: You modified the default resources location to `src/main/config` not sure why.